# Сложный маршрут в ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Разрабатываю API для веб сервиса, у меня появилась потребность создать такой маршрут `/api/Clients/{id}/Detalis/{id}/Units`
Подскажите как прописать его шаблон для контроллера и как вообще создать контроллер  таким маршрутом.

Comment: Это ведь разные идентификаторы? `/api/Clients/{clientId}/Details{detailId}/Units`. И у самого метода параметры `int clientId` и `int detailsId`.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, да, разные. Один относится к клиенту, другой к его деталям